# Loop not updating range.row or range.column

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to do a simple loops for my spreadsheet where it Loops through a range and checks if the row is empty and if it is not it then loops through a range of columns and checks if they are empty and if one is then it sets a message.

The problem is that everytime it goes through the loop ro.value and col.value update correctly but the colums number and row number do not so the message i set is always the same regardless of which row or column has a blank cell.

Here is my code:

```
Dim RoRange As range
Dim Ro As range
Dim Col As range
Dim ColRange As range
Set RoRange = Worksheets("Home").range("LineDescs")
Set ColRange = Worksheets("Home").range("F24:N24")

For Each Ro In RoRange.Rows
    If Ro.Value <> "" Then
        For Each Col In ColRange.Columns
            If Col.Value = "" Then
                Set_Message ("Cell " & ColRange.Column & ":" & RoRange.Row & " is Empty!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    End If

Next
```

"LineDescs" is a named range in my spreadsheet.
Please ask if you need anything explained thanks!

Comment: Presumably these are single row/column ranges? Your message line should refer to Ro and Col rather than RoRange and ColRange which are fixed.

Comment: What size is LineDescs? You can't check the value of multiple cells as you have in your first If statement.

Comment: @SJR You are correct indded sir about Ro and Col ! Thankyou very much. Feel free to put that as an asnwer and i will mark it correct! Simple thing apprently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message should refer to `Ro` and `Col` as they are the variables referred to in your loop. `RoRange` and `ColRange` are fixed so your message will always be the same.

(Note that to check the value of a range of cells you have to loop through each.)

```
For Each Ro In RoRange.Rows
    If Ro.Value <> "" Then
        For Each Col In ColRange.Columns
            If Col.Value = "" Then
                Set_Message ("Cell " & Col.Column & ":" & Ro.Row & " is Empty!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    End If

Next
```

Comment: If the columns are more than 1, then `If Col.Value = "" Then` should give error 13.

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether a whole `Row` or  a whole `Column` in Excel is empty like this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Rows(1) = ""
End Sub
```

throws `Type mismatch (Error 13)`. This is exactly what is happening here:

```
For Each Ro In RoRange.Rows
    If Ro.Value <> "" Then
```

---

Thus, if you want to check whether a row is without any filled out cells then something like this is ok:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRow As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    With wks
        For Each myRow In .Range("A1:B10").Rows

            For Each myCell In myRow.Cells
                If myCell <> "" Then
                    .Cells(myCell.Row, 3) = "NOT EMPTY"
                    .Cells(myCell.Row, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                End If
            Next myCell

            With .Cells(myRow.Row, 3)
                If .Value2 <> "NOT EMPTY" Then
                    .Value2 = "EMPTY"
                    .Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]